# Console Error on webpage - Javascript

Tags: javascript, web

Hello if you go to my site and open up the developer tools I keep getting an error can anyone tell what might be causing that?

I can add more details if necessary just let me know.

http://tommy2.bitballoon.com/

Thanks,

Tom

Comment: Please [edit] your question to quote the error message, and show the relevant code. If you're not sure which code is relevant, you can click on the line number that the console shows with the error and that should show you the code that went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the following code:

```
$("#submitbtn").on(click, function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    return false
})
```

it should be:

```
$("#submitbtn").on("click", function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    return false
})
```

(Note on the double strings before and after click)

---

In order to debug your code first take atention to the error message, then click on the file that its throwing the error

[image: Error message]

Once clicked, if your code has been minified you can click in the braces to prettify it:

[image: Minified code]

So once clicked the curly braces you will get this, understanding the error message will give you where is the issue:

[image: Prettified error message]

Comment: @zerkms They weren't already?

Comment: @Barmar it does not matter: the answer should contain at least some information on debugging techniques so that it was helpful to more than 1 person.

Comment: @zerkms your constructive criticism is welcome and I hope my answer satifies you, however next time instead of to criticize the answer you could give it the apport instantly

Comment: "however next time instead of to criticize the answer you could give it the apport instantly" --- you may familiarise yourself with how SO works first: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300837/251311

Comment: Got it, thanks for the url. But again, in my personal opinion, helping to improve an answer is more usefull than only giving a critique, once someone has shared the improvement the user that has asked will inmediately know about it and the owner of the answer can add the modification later, while only giving the critique you wait for the owner of the answer to modify it

Comment: "once someone has shared the improvement the user that has asked will inmediately know about it" --- once they got an answer they copy-pasted it and never would open the page again.

Comment: If so, even you paste all the documentation, insert 20 examples, you make a video tutorial to explain the code and send him books for free, the result would be the same as if the answer was only code, so your comment isnt valid. Also, as you mentioned before, it is to help "more than 1 person"... However, we are going very off topic, we can continue this debate in the meta forum if you want.